# SCSS Custom Linter not inside mixins nor functions

Tags: ruby, sass, scss-lint

I have this linter rule, that verifies that for every variable there is a use of `!default`:

```
module SCSSLint
  # Reports the use of !default in properties.
  class Linter::DefaultRule < Linter
    include LinterRegistry

    def visit_variable(node)
      return if source_from_range(node.source_range).include?('!default')

      add_lint(node, '!default should be used')
    end
  end
end
```

And I want it to only check global variables, and not variables inside a `function` or a `mixin`.

How can I make it ignore non-globally scoped variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is a viable solution:

```
module SCSSLint
  # Reports the use of !default at the end of variable declarations.
  class Linter::DefaultRule < Linter
    include LinterRegistry

    def visit_function(node)
      return true
    end

    def visit_variable(node)
      return if source_from_range(node.source_range).include?('!default')

      return unless node_ancestor(node, 2).nil?

      add_lint(node, '!default should be used')
    end
  end
end
```